# Futuristic/dystopian short story about a man living in a hive society trying to meet his dying mother

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

I'm trying to find a short story I read many years ago about a guy living in a "hive" society in which everyone lives in cells, connected (I think) by computers; the substance of the narrative is that the protagonist is attempting to contact his mother, who he's been told is dying, and whom he's never met, even though they've lived in this hive together for however long (apparently in this world children are separated from their mothers in infancy). I think the story was in a science-fiction collection, and I read it in the 1980's.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. To make identification easier, please review the [tag info wiki](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) for [tag:identification-request] questions and supply as much of the suggested information there as you can: how long ago you read the story; how old the book in which you read it seemed to be (approximate date of publication); what the physical book looked like, or if you read it online, what site, etc. Those pieces of data help narrow down the story. Please edit your question to include this information rather tha

Comment: ... rather than adding this info in the comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You may be thinking of ["The Machine Stops"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41186), a science fiction novelette by [E. M. Forster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E._M._Forster), which you might have read in one of [these compilations](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?41186); it can be borrowed from the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/machinestops0000unse/mode/2up). It matches your description pretty well, except that the mother is not dying.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Machine_Stops) plot summary:

> The story describes a world in which most of the human population has lost the ability to live on the surface of the Earth. Each individual now lives in isolation below ground in a standard room, with all bodily and spiritual needs met by the omnipotent, global Machine. Travel is permitted, but is unpopular and rarely necessary. Communication is made via a kind of instant messaging/video conferencing machine with which people conduct their only activity: the sharing of ideas and what passes for knowledge.
>
> The two main characters, Vashti and her son Kuno, live on opposite sides of the world. Vashti is content with her life, which, like most inhabitants of the world, she spends producing and endlessly discussing secondhand 'ideas'. Her son Kuno, however, is a sensualist and a rebel. He persuades a reluctant Vashti to endure the journey (and the resultant unwelcome personal interaction) to his room. There, he tells her of his disenchantment with the sanitised, mechanical world.
>
> He confides to her that he has visited the surface of the Earth without permission and that he saw other humans living outside the world of the Machine. However, the Machine recaptures him, and he is threatened with 'Homelessness': expulsion from the underground environment and presumed death. Vashti, however, dismisses her son's concerns as dangerous madness and returns to her part of the world.
>
> As time passes, and Vashti continues the routine of her daily life, there are two important developments. First, individuals are no longer permitted access to the respirators which are needed to visit the earth's surface. Most welcome this development, as they are sceptical and fearful of first-hand experience and of those who desire it. Secondly, "Technopoly", a kind of religion, is established, in which the Machine is the object of worship. People forget that humans created the Machine, and treat it as a mystical entity whose needs supersede their own.
>
> Those who do not accept the deity of the Machine are viewed as 'unmechanical' and threatened with Homelessness. The Mending Apparatus – the system charged with repairing defects that appear in the Machine proper – has also failed by this time, but concerns about this are dismissed in the context of the supposed omnipotence of the Machine itself.
>
> During this time, Kuno is transferred to a room near Vashti's. He comes to believe that the Machine is breaking down, and tells her cryptically "The Machine stops." Vashti continues with her life, but eventually defects begin to appear in the Machine. At first, humans accept the deteriorations as the whim of the Machine, to which they are now wholly subservient, but the situation continues to deteriorate as the knowledge of how to repair the Machine has been lost.
>
> Finally, the Machine collapses, bringing 'civilisation' down with it. Kuno comes to Vashti's ruined room. Before they both perish, they realise that humanity and its connection to the natural world are what truly matters, and that it will fall to the surface-dwellers who still exist to rebuild the human race and to prevent the mistake of the Machine from being repeated.

Comment: See also: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/97207/book-set-underground-everyone-lives-in-pods-woman-wants-to-see-her-son